# Mistake while installing

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I was trying to install Ubuntu to a Windows 7 PC.I got as far as loading the OS without an external drive by means of UNetbootin and went on with the final installation step. There I was asked to create partition and I went on to do so, de-allocating all space for Windows. Then without much thought, I restarted the computer and now it does not load anything at all, except for a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I would like to know what went wrong while I rebooted, more specifically have I deleted both windows and Ubuntu from the system? Also is there a way to correct this error?
Plus I am kind of new with this sort of thing, hence pardon my lack of in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) *I... de-allocated all space for Windows... (t)hen...I restarted the computer and now it does not load anything at all, except for a black screen with a blinking cursor.*
You didn't complete the installation, so there's no boot manager, no GRUB, no operating system. Time to start over by [making a Live USB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0); that links to [Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) and [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) instructions to make a booting Ubuntu LiveUSB.

The [installation instructions for Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) are the same, whether you made your LiveUSB with Windows or with Ubuntu.

When you reach step [6, Allocate Drive Space](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5), choose the first option shown there to Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu, which will fix the broken disk partition and give it all to Ubuntu.

2) *...have I deleted both windows and Ubuntu from the system?* Yes.

3) *...is there a way to correct this error?* At your level of expertise, no. It would require a skilled professional, knowledgeable in disk partition recovery. Only you can determine whether it is worth the cost to recover what was on that drive.

Comment: I have been able to get it up and working successfully.